# How to extract test case results using Jira Rest API

Tags: json, automated-tests, jira-rest-api, python-jira, jira-xray

When I use the Rest API to extract the json file, I am able to view all the issues and fields. However, none of these fields contain any information about the tests run. I am able to see the tests and their result on my Jira software online. Could someone help me with trying to locate where I could get the information of the test cases and executions in the JSON file?

Comment: 1) can you please clarify if you're using Xray on Jira cloud or Xray on Jira server/datacenter? 2) can you please provide an example of the exact request, including the endpoint you're calling, and the answer you're obtaining?

Comment: @Sérgio, Would I need Xray to access pre-existing tests? Would I not be able to access test execution results using Rest API the same way that I can access, for example,  bug details, task summary, etc?

Comment: You need access to Xray's Test and Test Execution issues . Have you seen my previous comment/questions? Would be helpful so we can provide you some tips

Comment: @Sérgio, to configure my Xray with my project, what do I do to configure the issue types for tests, test execution, etc. when this is how my summary page looks like once i choose the project to configure:     Issue Types
Xray Entity Issue Type Description
Test Not configured 
Precondition Not configured 
Test Set Not configured 
Test Plan Not configured 
Test Execution Not configured

Comment: It seems that you're using Xray on Jira Cloud. Please follow the quick setup instructions mentioned here: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Quick+Setup#QuickSetup-ConfigureXrayIssueTypesinyourproject
Nevertheless, it would be helpful if you could update your original question with the example of the exact REST API request, including the endpoint you're calling, and the answer you're obtaining, so we can be able to help out.
Please note: the Jira project you're trying to configure doesn't seem to be related with the API request you mentioned.. or is it?

Comment: @Sérgio, I was able to setup the Xray on Jira cloud. You are correct in your last sentence, the two are not related. For my individual project, I am using this query and request: query = {
    'jql' : 'type = "Test Execution"'

}
response = requests.get(url, headers= headers, params = query, auth = (env['api_user'], env['API_TOKEN'])).  Using this, I try to find the status of the tests within the test execution but none of the keys in the dictionary of the JSON point me to the status of the tests(passed, failed, to do).

Comment: Ok. I'll provide an answer for initial question then (not here on the comments).
Just as a note: on StackOverflow we are advised to create separate questions, to make it more clear for everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Xray for Jira Cloud](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/About+Xray), which is a different product from Xray for Jira server/datacenter, provides both a [REST API](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/REST+API) and a [GraphQL API](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/GraphQL+API).
To obtain the test results associated with a given Test Execution, you need to use the GraphQL API.

First, you need to [authenticate using the REST API](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Authentication+-+REST+v2) and client id/secret pair, that will give you a token.
Having the token, you can make the GraphQL request.
You can either use the  `getTestExecution` method, but it will require you to know the Test Execution issue id.
Instead, you can use `getTestExecutions` which allows you to provide a JQL even if that JQL just returns a single Test Execution issue based on its issue key.
In GraphQL you can specify what you want to return... like the "test" object, or the "testRuns" object. The "tests" object only provides info about the related Test issues and the respective Jira fields. In this case, what you want is the "testRuns" object instead.

I've built an example of a Python script using the `gql` graphql client library, doing either a simple request or a more detailed request. The simple may be good enough for what you need.
You need to update the values for:

- the client id and client secret used for authenticating the request
- the Test Execution issue key that you want to obtain info from

```py
from gql import gql, Client
from gql.transport.aiohttp import AIOHTTPTransport
#from gql.transport.requests import RequestsHTTPTransport
import requests
import json
import os

xray_cloud_base_url = "https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v2"
client_id = os.getenv('CLIENT_ID', "215FFD69FE4644728C72182E00000000")
client_secret = os.getenv('CLIENT_SECRET',"1c00f8f22f56a8684d7c18cd6147ce2787d95e4da9f3bfb0af8f02ec00000000")

# endpoint doc for authenticating and obtaining token from Xray Cloud: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Authentication+-+REST+v2
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
auth_data = { "client_id": client_id, "client_secret": client_secret }
response = requests.post(f'{xray_cloud_base_url}/authenticate', data=json.dumps(auth_data), headers=headers)
auth_token = response.json()
print(auth_token)


xray_cloud_graphql_url = "https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v2/graphql"

# Select your transport with a defined url endpoint
transport = AIOHTTPTransport(
  url=xray_cloud_graphql_url,
  headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {auth_token}'}
)


# Create a GraphQL client using the defined transport
client = Client(transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=True)

# detailed query to return info about the test runs, related tests.. 
detailed_query = gql(
    """
query
{
    getTestExecutions(jql: "key=CALC-141", limit: 1) {
        results{
          issueId
          jira(fields: ["key"])
    
          testRuns(limit: 100){
            results{
              id
              status{
                name
                description
              }
              comment
              testType{
                name
              }
              evidence{
                filename
              }
              defects
              executedById
              startedOn
              finishedOn
              assigneeId

              steps {
                  id
                  action
                  data
                  result
              }

              scenarioType
              gherkin
              examples {
                  id
                  status {
                      name
                      description
                  }
                  duration
              }

              unstructured
              
              customFields {
                  id
                  name
                  values
              }

              preconditions(limit:10) {
                results{
                    preconditionRef {
                        issueId
                        jira(fields: ["key"])
                    }
                    definition
                }
              }
              test {
                  issueId
                  jira(fields: ["key"])
                    projectId
                    testType {
                        name
                        kind
                    }
              }
              
            }
        }

    }
  }
}


"""
)


# simple query, to obtain the test runs, and their status, for a given Test Execution 
simple_query = gql(
    """
query
{
    getTestExecutions(jql: "key=CALC-141", limit: 1) {
        results{

          testRuns(limit: 100){
            results{

              test {
                  jira(fields: ["key"])
              }

              status{
                name
              }

            }
        }

    }
  }
}


"""
)

# Execute the query on the transport
result = client.execute(simple_query)
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

Side note: there is a GH repository with [some Postman collections](https://github.com/Xray-App/xray-postman-collections) that you can import, with some examples that you can try out and adjust to your needs.

Comment: the first part of your explanation was very helpful. I was able to install and authenticate my Xray now. However, I am having trouble understanding the request example. Are they placeholders for actual values? Could you please explain it in a simpler way? Thanks a lot for your help so far!

Comment: It's the body of a GraphQL request. In GraphQL you can specify the information you want to be returned, depending on what the server is able to provide you. You can try perhaps Insomnia which provides auto-complete for GraphQL requests. you can see the GraphQL schema dcoumentation for Xray here: https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/doc/graphql/

Comment: Is there any video that could maybe guide me through this process? The documentation does not seem to explain how I would configure the GraphQL into my script.

Comment: No, there are no videos specific for that but I would recommend you to have a look at some general videos or resources about graphql, then you just need to adapt the graphql query you need

Comment: I've updated my previous answer with a working code snippet; feel free to download it, adjust it, and try it out. You have to install gql and gql[aiohttp] using "pip install .."

Comment: Thank you so much Sergio, I have got it to work. i really appreciate all the help!

Comment: You're welcome. I would appreciate if you could mark my answer as correct :) thanks in advance

Comment: On the same note, is there any way I could obtain the summary of the test executions? I did not find a query for this on GraphQL from the documentation.

Comment: Just add this after the "results {" on the simple_query variable
jira(fields: ["summary"])

Comment: I tried this earlier but this gives me the summary of the test itself. However, I am looking for the summary of each test execution under the test.

Comment: If you want to obtain the summary of the test execution issue, then add right after the first "results". If you  want to obtain the summary of each test associated with each testrun, then add after the "test" section.